# Why does converting `interface{}` back to slice cause an additional heap allocation?

Tags: performance, go

```golang
func BenchmarkPool(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    p := sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} {
        return make([]byte, 1024)
    }}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bts := p.Get().([]byte)
        p.Put(bts)
    }
}
```

This benchmark gives the following output in go1.19.5.

```bash
BenchmarkPool
BenchmarkPool-10        47578498            24.47 ns/op       24 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

When use `*[]byte`, things get different:

```golang
func BenchmarkPool(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    p := sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} {
        bts := make([]byte, 1024)
        return &bts
    }}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bts := p.Get().(*[]byte)
        p.Put(bts)
    }
}
```

```bash
BenchmarkPool
BenchmarkPool-10        142008002            8.581 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

It seems that convert `interface{}` back to slice cause an additional heap allocation.
Why does Go need this additional allocation? What's the design consideration under it?

Comment: ["Get may choose to ignore the pool and treat it as empty."](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Pool.Get) Also, the work Pool is doing isn't free. Note that you're still doing *much* better than 1024 B/op.

Comment: @Peter I have updated the question. Because `b.N` is big enough, the armorized allocs should be zero, not one. There must be something fires an additional escape analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the conversion of `any` to `[]byte` that causes allocation, it is the conversion of `[]byte` to `any` that does. `p.Put(bts)` implicitly casts the argument `bts` to `any` before passing it to `(*sync.Pool).Put`. An interface as in GoGC 1.19 is implemented as a pair of pointers, one to the type metadata and one to the actual object, and it is the second pointer that escapes to the pool in this case that results in the slice object being allocated. This does not only hold for slice types but also any other non-pointer types.

For a pointer, such as a `*[]byte`, the compiler performs an optimisation that put its value directly into the `iface` struct, which removes the allocation of a `*[]byte` instance when converting to an interface. As a result, it is often recommended to put the pointer in pools instead of the struct themselves.

Answer (score 1):

A slice is meant to be "dynamic" in the sense that you allocate and discard the header and backing array as needed. When you pool the `[]byte` value, the slice header is always copied, so all that is essentially reused is the backing array, and you need to allocate the extra 24 bytes for the header every time to return the slice to the pool. In other words, you can't reuse the slice header when you are only passing in a copy.

If you want the pool to store and reuse an entire slice value, then you want to use `*[]byte` because you need a pointer to the value you want to store in the pool. This would also allow you to return a differently sized slice value to the pool (possibly enlarged with append), which may or may not be desirable for your use case.

If you want only a statically sized buffer for reuse, then what you want is an array, or more specifically, a pointer to an array, which makes it much clearer what the expectations are of the pooled value.

```
func BenchmarkPool(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    p := sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} {
        return &[1024]byte{}
    }}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        buff := p.Get().(*[1024]byte)
        p.Put(buff)
    }
}
```

You can allocate a slice around that array as needed, and convert it back to an array when returning it to the pool.

Comment: I think Quân Anh Mai touch the core of the problem. When pool the `[]byte` value, it is converted to `any`, which causes `[]byte` escaping to heap. If I store the returned `any` of `Pool.Get`, and put `any` back to pool, no escape will happen. If we have a generic version of `sync.Pool`, the `[]byte` will be prefered rather than `*[]byte`.

Comment: @tocrafty, that's what I was trying to imply by saying you need to reallocate the bytes when you return the slice to the pool. My main point was that this is all moot when you consider that the slice header is copied anyway (even if there were a generic pool), so all you are really pooling is the underlying array, which you can do explicitly.

Comment: @JimB Actually I think that most of the time you want to pool the backing buffer and not the slice header. And pooling the slice instead of an explicit arrays gives more flexibilities, as Go does not allow runtime-length arrays. As a result, I agree with @tocrafty that with a generics `sync.Pool`, pooling a `[]byte` is preferable as it is more flexible than pooling a `*[N]byte` and it eliminates one allocation for each pooled object and a level of indirection compared to `*[]byte`.

Comment: @QuânAnhMai, I personally would start by pooling a static array, because that is what the pool is allocating, and the same object should be put back into the pool for consistency. Returning a slice with a possibly different backing array, maybe even with part of the array inaccessible due to slicing could lead to unexpected changes in allocation and performance (I would test of course ;)). A generic pool would be nice and let you skip the pointer in `*[]byte`, but I think a side effect of the interface is that the pointer actually makes you think more closely about about what you are caching.